# Prince of Persia (2008): Quick Response Prompts

Tags: pc, prince-of-persia-2008

I am looking for some help with getting a better grasp on the combat system in Prince of Persia (the cel-shaded iteration from 2008).

I do well enough through most everything else, but the quick prompt combat queues are beyond me. Can anyone help me with better anticipating the prompts that accompany the combat? I'm not terrible at executing the combos, but hitting the right key (playing on the PC) leaves me at a total loss.

I'm sure that there is a degree of motor response that I may be lacking, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that your referring to the attacks that require you to press a key to counter/dodge the attack

With the bosses (Hunter, Alchemist, Warrior & Concubine), each quick prompt combat response will be tied to a particular attack animation. It will take you a a short while, but eventually you'll begin to recognise which animation is tied to which key press.

I have to admit they are quite difficult to get the hang of and I often miss one, but you'll eventually begin to recognise them